# How to accept multiline text and change it to singleline?

Tags: asp.net

I want to make my textbox to be able to receive multiline text from paste function and change it to single line as example below:

```
i want to change
this multiline text
just into single line.
please help
```

into

```
i want to change this multiline text just into single line. please help
```

I try to change the *textmode* to *singleline* but it end up just take the first line only. How can i do this? Below is my code. Many thanks!

```
<asp:Textbox id="Textbox" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="LongTextBox" Width="370px" Runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" autocomplete="off" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:Textbox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the line breaks with a space.

```
string value = Textbox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", " ");
```

But if the text already contained a space before or after the line break, you'll get 2 spaces.

```
i want to change
 this multiline text
 just into single line.
please help
```

so you could also do this

```
string value = TextBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", " ").Replace("  ", " ");
```

Comment: Or even: `string value = TextBox1.Text.Replace("\r", "").Replace(" \n", " ").Replace("\n ", " ").Replace("\n", " ");`. That is, trim carriage return, replace space + newline with space, then newline + space with space then remaining single newlines with space. The case space + newline + space is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: Worth considering use of Environment.Newline in place of "\r\n".